# Laravel - Problems with session (Login redirect / 419 Session Expired)

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-cookies, csrf

We have five Laravel projects in the same server, in two of the projects we have problems with the session, when one of our users is browsing the portal, they're sometimes redirected to the login page for no reason, if we return to the previous page the session still exists, other times when a form is submitted it shows error **'419 session expired'**, even when the form has the **'@CSRF'** token, the sessions were migrated to be handled in the database which made the problem little less frequent however continues to exist.

Comment: May be you need to verify permissions on storage folder ? that apache or nginx can write sessions, it just a just a hint.

Comment: We have already verified the permissions and everything seems to be correct, anyway the sessions are handled by the database, so session folder is not need it... Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: Did you move projects folder or domain ? another thing that can cause the csrf issue is the generated key with "php artisan key:generate".

If project moved, new key need to be generated and config:cache cleared.